# How do i take user input from keyboard in my crossword game instead of the popup with the alphabets

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

```js
function initvkeyboard(){
                var chars = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",]
                for(var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
                    $("#kbtnlist").append("<div class='kbtn' onclick=typechar('"+chars[i]+"')>"+chars[i]+"</div>")
                }
            }
```

I am making a crossword game this is a javascript function which accepts the input from the popup and displays it. Instead of it i want to give keyboard access to this game how do i make this function to get user input instead from my keyboard and not print the popup

```js
function initvkeyboard(){
    Window.location = ""+ input.value;

    for(var i = 0; i<input; i++){
        $("#kbtnlist").append("<div class='kbtn' onclick=typechar('"+chars[i]+"')>"+chars[i]+"</div>")
    }
}
```

this is what i am trying to do i want to give keyboard access to my crossword game and not give popup

Comment: `Window.location = ""+ input.value;` ? What is that about?

Comment: @trincot idk i got this from google i thought it would work so i put it in there

Comment: I would never copy code of which I have no idea what it is doing.

Comment: how do i solve it just say that !

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want me to say. I already posted an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a key-down listener on the document level:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.key.length == 1 && e.key >= "a" && e.key <= "z") {
        typechar(e.key);
    }
});
```

Here is a demo:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.key.length == 1 && e.key >= "a" && e.key <= "z") {
        typechar(e.key);
    }
});

// The function you did not provide, so this is just a demo
function typechar(key) { 
    const output = document.getElementById("typearea");
    output.textContent += key; 
}
```

```html
Click on this area and then start typing:
<div id="typearea"></div>
```

Comment: its not making any changes @trincot

Comment: Made a correction and added a runnable snippet to demo it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener to the document to capture keyboard input. Then you can check if the pressed key is a letter (a-z) and then call your `typechar` function.

Here is the updated code:

```
function initvkeyboard() {
  document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) {
      var char = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();
      typechar(char);
    }
  });

  var chars = [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d",
    "e",
    "f",
    "g",
    "h",
    "i",
    "j",
    "k",
    "l",
    "m",
    "n",
    "o",
    "p",
    "q",
    "r",
    "s",
    "t",
    "u",
    "v",
    "w",
    "x",
    "y",
    "z",
  ];

  for(var i = 0; i<input; i++){
    $("#kbtnlist").append("<div class='kbtn' onclick=typechar('"+chars[i]+"')>"+chars[i]+"</div>")
  }
}
```

Comment: after using this what you just wrote now my  crossword grid is also not visible. @mridul